# jQuery styling in Leaflet popup

Tags: jquery, leaflet

Is it possible to add jQuery styling to a div in a Leaflet popup?

It's a bit problematic because the popup is created when you click the marker in Leaflet. Say I want to style a div with a .class inside the popup with jQuery. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, since you didn't provide any code, but css doesn't rely on dom elements existing when the stylesheets are loaded. So you should be able to construct your html with classes as usual, and reference those classes in your stylesheet.

Edit:

To manipulate the contents of newly created elements with html you could include the sub-widget initialization in the code that creates the original popup.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking more of a jquery plugin function on a div. Like a scroller for example.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to post your code.

Normally you can use

```
$(.class).css({ 'property':'value', 'property2':'value2' })
```

in your jQuery to edit css things after your css has finished loading.